# Uncaught ReferenceError: swapImage is not defines

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to this but here is the deal.

At first I was having trouble because only one of my javascript elements would display.  I've gotten some help from matt ellen and it came to my attention that I had window.onload in my code twice.  Ive since removed them from the functions and added a line where I include both functions.

```
<head>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="bavafavicon"/>
    <title>Berlin Airlift Veterans Association: News</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

</head>

<body id="news">
    <div id="container">

        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="leftblue"></div>
        <div id="right"></div>
        <div id="topyellow"></div>
        <div id="topred"></div>

        <div id="slider">           
            <script type="javascript"> 
                var i = 0; var path = new Array(); 
                    path[0] = "1.jpg"; 
                    path[1] = "2.jpg"; 
                    path[2] = "3.jpg"; 
                    path[3] = "4.jpg";
                    path[4] = "5.jpg";
                    path[5] = "6.jpg";
                function swapImage() 
                    { 
                        document.slide.src = path[i]; 
                        if(i < path.length - 1) i++; 
                        else i = 0; 
                        setTimeout("swapImage()",5500); 
                    } 
            </script> 
            <img name="slide"/>
        </div>

            <ul id="head_nav">
                <li><a href="index.htm" class="currentButton">NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutbava.htm" class="button">ABOUT BAVA</a></li>
                <li><a href="history.htm" class="button">HISTORY</a></li>
                <li><a href="biographies.htm" class="button">BIOGRAPHIES</a></li>
                <li><a href="calendar.htm" class="button">CALENDAR</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.htm" class="button">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="links.htm" class="button">LINKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="donate.htm" class="button">DONATE</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="headlogo">
                <img src="BAVA.png" alt="BAVA logo" width="150" height="150"/>
            </div>
            <div id="subscribe">Sign up for BAVA updates!<br>

                <img src="emailBomb.png" alt="emailBomb" id="emailBomb" width="150" height="300"/>
                <form action="demo_form.asp">
                    E-mail: <input type="email" name="userid">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br></form> 

<script type="javascript">

function GetClock(){
tzOffset = +2;

d = new Date();
dx = d.toGMTString();
dx = dx.substr(0,dx.length -3);
d.setTime(Date.parse(dx))
d.setHours(d.getHours() + tzOffset);
nday   = d.getDay();
nmonth = d.getMonth();
ndate  = d.getDate();
nyear = d.getYear();
nhour  = d.getHours();
nmin   = d.getMinutes();
if(nyear<1000) nyear=nyear+1900;

if(nmin <= 9){nmin="0"+nmin}


document.getElementById('berlinClock').innerHTML=""+(nmonth+1)+"/"+ndate+"/"+nyear+"       "+nhour+":"+nmin+"";
setTimeout("GetClock()", 1000);
}
</script> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    window.onload = function() { swapImage(); GetClock(); };
                </script>               
<div id="berlinClock"></div>



            </div>


        </div>
    <footer>
        <div id="footer">
            <p><i>15 N. College Ave, Newton, NC 28658   |   (828) 466-3410</i></p>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>
```

Im no longer using an external js.

Comment: console errors? In javascript the order of your scripts is really important so be case of it, it is not a good practice to place your scrpt where your html needs it, you normally place them in the head section, or at the bottom of your document (wich is what I like to do), there are alot of opinions of where to place them, but i think to place them in the bottom is the best way(that works really good for me)

Comment: the bottom of the head? or body?

Comment: Bottom of the body is a good place, to make sure all the page DOM is loaded. Also, when you are doing javascript and something does not work, **always** open your **Javascript console** (F12 on your keyboard) to see any errors and at which line of your code they appear.

Comment: Hmm its not showing any errors.  Its so weird.  I erase the clock java and the slider appears....

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the berlinTime.js

Comment: I would post it right here but its too many characters...

Comment: i just edited the post and added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `window.onload` twice. It will be the second one, which is `GetClock`, which will be run, not the first.

You need to add a function call that calls both after you've declared both functions, and then remove the other assignments to onload.

```
window.onload = function() { swapImage(); GetClock(); };
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cm299/) to demonstrate what I mean.

As an aside; your language attribute is incorrect in your first script tag. It should be `javascript` not `JavasScript/text`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know although this doesn't solve the problem.  At least Im one step closer to making it as good as it can be

Comment: Sorry, I was hasty. I think I've found the issue.

Comment: Man that would be sweet!

Comment: Thank you!  Do you think you could explain how to do that to someone that isn't at all savy with Java.  Im learning the html, and copied and pasted the java.

Someone like me, when I read that, I start wondering do I just paste the code you provided at the bottom of the second java script and then remove the onload from the first....  Sorry man, Im that guy today...

Comment: btw this is volunteer work, im not getting paid.  I just like helping out veterans and I have to make a website for school so I gave myself a homework assignment that was a little out of my league...

Comment: If you follow the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cm299/) link I've added, you can see what I mean. I've added in your belinClock script inline, rather than as a resource (slightly edited), and then I've set the `onload` in another script tag just below, to be sure that that assignment happens last.

Comment: you should keep your script as a resource, but you should remove the `window.onload=GetClock` from it.

Comment: now they both dont work.  Its all good guys, don't worry about it.  As much as I want a clock on this website its not that serious I guess.

Comment: OK. So then there is probably an error message. push f12 and hit refresh to see what come up

Comment: Can you edit your question to add in what your code looks like now?

Comment: @user3756283 The code you updated in your question works if you simply replace all `<script type="javascript">` with `<script type="text/javascript">`